# How do I check if a string contains any characters from a given set of characters represented in another string?

Tags: java, regex, string, char

How do I check if a list of characters are in a String, for example "ABCDEFGH" how do I check if any one of those is in a string.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

use regular expression in java to check using `str.matches(regex_here)`
[regex in java](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html)

for example:

```
    if("asdhAkldffl".matches(".*[ABCDEFGH].*"))
    {
        System.out.println("yes");
    }
```

Comment: what about locale sensitivity?

Answer (score 29):

The cleanest way to implement this is using [StringUtils.containsAny(String, String)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#containsAny-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-)

```
package com.sandbox;

import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertFalse;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

public class SandboxTest {

    @Test
    public void testQuestionInput() {
        assertTrue(StringUtils.containsAny("39823839A983923", "ABCDEFGH"));
        assertTrue(StringUtils.containsAny("A", "ABCDEFGH"));
        assertTrue(StringUtils.containsAny("ABCDEFGH", "ABCDEFGH"));
        assertTrue(StringUtils.containsAny("AB", "ABCDEFGH"));
        assertFalse(StringUtils.containsAny("39823839983923", "ABCDEFGH"));
        assertFalse(StringUtils.containsAny("", "ABCDEFGH"));
    }

}
```

Maven dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: @advocate Probably because it's not build into java.  You have to download Apache Commons Lang to get it.  http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/  Make sure to add it to your classpath.

Comment: Thanks! For anyone else you need to unzip the download package (I recommend in your project folder). Right click your project in Eclipse -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path -> Add External Jars -> Select the commons lang jars. You will also need the right version number in your inport statement: import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

Comment: This should be the accepted answer - it is cleaner, simpler and in my tests for verifying Windows file names for reserved characters using a pre-compiled RegEx (e.g. Pattern.compile(".*?[<>:\"/\\|?*]+?.*")), StringUtils.containsAny performed ~6 times faster.

Answer (score 4):

From Guava: [CharMatcher.matchesAnyOf](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/16.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html#matchesAnyOf(java.lang.CharSequence))

```
private static final CharMatcher CHARACTERS = CharMatcher.anyOf("ABCDEFGH");
assertTrue(CHARACTERS.matchesAnyOf("39823839A983923"));
```

Answer (score 3):

If `"ABCDEFGH"` is in a string variable, the regular expression solution is not good. It will not work if the string contains any character that has a special meaning in regular expressions. Instead I suggest:

```
    Set<Character> charsToTestFor = "ABCDEFGH".chars()
            .mapToObj(ch -> Character.valueOf((char) ch))
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    String stringToTest = "asdhAkldffl";
    boolean anyCharInString = stringToTest.chars()
            .anyMatch(ch -> charsToTestFor.contains(Character.valueOf((char) ch)));
    System.out.println("Does " + stringToTest + " contain any of " + charsToTestFor + "? " + anyCharInString);
```

With the strings `asdhAkldffl` and `ABCDEFGH` this snippet outputs:

> Does asdhAkldffl contain any of [A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H]? true

Comment: I hadn't considered this when I gave my answer. This is a good point.  There are ways to get around it.  You could escape special characters with a "\". I'm not saying this as an "on the other hand," I'm just letting others know every angle.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a newbie question, so i will give you the easies method i can think of: [using indexof](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/indexOf.html) complex version include [regex](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) you can try if you want.

Answer (score 1):

This is how it can be achieved using Pattern and Matcher,

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^A-Za-z0-9 ]");
Matcher m = p.matcher(trString);
boolean hasSpecialChars = m.find();
```

Answer (score -2):

This seems like a Homework question... -_-

You can use the String.contains() function.
For example:

```
"string".contains("a");
String str = "wasd";
str.contains("a");
```

but you will need to call it once per every character you want to check for.

Comment: This is a inefficient solution, using regex is better.

Comment: I postedit because it is simpler and easier to understand if you don't know regex yet.

Comment: Yeah but good luck if you want to check if it contains only numeric data with this method.

Comment: Even if it is. That is not an acceptable attitude to answer.

Comment: The question asked for a list of characters, not a single one