# How do you write a code that Returns true if s(a string) contains none of the characters found in chars(another string) or false otherwise

Tags: java

How do you write a code that Returns true if s(a string) contains none of the characters found in chars(another string) or false otherwise?

```java
char[] original = s.toCharArray(); 


char [] sub = chars.toCharArray();

for(int i = 0; i <s.length(); i++)

{

if (s.contains(chars)

{

return true;

}

}

return false;
```

Comment: Nevermind how I write it, how will you write it since it's your homework?

Comment: If you're thrown by the logic as presented, try inverting it... first write a code that returns `true` if a string *does* contain some characters from another string. And then return the negation of that function.

Comment: This is fairly straight forward. Have you looked at the [String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) reference? Please post what you have tried.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if a string contains a list of characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14392270/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-contains-a-list-of-characters)

Comment: Negate the suggested dupe

Comment: char[] original = s.toCharArray(); 
     char [] sub = chars.toCharArray();
     for(int i = 0; i <s.length(); i++)
     {
      if(original.l)
      {
       return true;
      }
     }
     return false;

Comment: you want us to explain the 'contains' method?

Comment: yeah pls when I try to say s.contains(char) { return true}.....this isn't working .thats why im confused

Comment: @aby12 that code also makes little sense. How exactly did you implement it? Don't explain it in a comment, edit your question and add the information there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code, the results are false, true.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(isNotContained("abc", "dc"));
        System.out.println(isNotContained("abc", "de"));
    }

    private static boolean isNotContained(final String source, final String target) {
        char[] original = source.toCharArray();
        for (char c : original) {
            if (target.contains(String.valueOf(c))) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```